# How can I figure out a users postal code if I have their latitude / longitude location? Need help writing a query

Tags: mysql, geolocation, location

I'm using HTML5 geolocation to collect the users lat / long and I need to figure out what their postal code is as well.  I have a database of all the lat / long for each postal code in the US & Canada.  How can I write a query to find out what their postal code is? Below, is an example of how the data is structured in the 'zips' table.

```
Country  PostalCode  Latitude  Longitude
USA      0051        40.813078 -73.046388
USA      00616       18.426456 -66.673779
```

I can't do a 'SELECT PostalCode FROM zips WHERE Latitude = *user.lat* AND Longitude = *user.long*'.  I believe I need to find the nearest lat / long.  Any suggestions on how I can write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to go through the entire zip code table, calculating the distance between the postal code latitude and longitude, and the users latitude and longitude.

Since the distances are relatively short, you can use the distance formula: `d = SQRT(((PCLA - ULA) ** 2) + ((PCLO - ULO) ** 2))`.  The answer is in degrees, not kilometers or miles.

Whichever postal code is the shortest distance from your user is **probably** the postal code.

Otherwise, you could just ask the user.  :-)

Look up the postal code they give you, calculate the distance, and see if it's a reasonable distance.

Here's a more precise formula for [calculating the distance between two earth coordinates](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlon_formula.html).

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.  However, I think asking the user may be the better option.  There is about a million records in this table and it probably wouldn't be the best idea to constantly be hitting it with that much data in it.

Comment: You're welcome.  We have a transaction in our application that does this distance calculation.  Our users want us to go to something like Google maps, but we're dragging our feet because of the cost of using Google enterprise wide.  However, we "encourage" our users to have the transaction open in one window, and have Google maps open in another window. :-)